# salto de linea en archivo.txt

Tags: python

```
        if (cont == 0):#si no tiene errores manda SINTAXIS OK
            cadena = 'linea'+" "+str(i)+" "+str(oracion)+" "+"SINTANXIS OK"+"\n"
        else:#sino manda todos los errores que tiene
            cadena = 'linea'+' '+str(i)+" "+str(oracion)+" "+str(cont)+" "+"ERROR(ES)"+"\n"
        archi.write(cadena)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la linea 0 quisiera que se mostrara como en la linea 1, pero la linea 0 hace salto de linea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero que nada hay algo erróneo en los ejemplos, esto

```
cadena = 'linea'+" "+str(i)+" "+str(oracion)+" "+"SINTANXIS OK"+"\n"
```

No puede generar esta salida:

```
Linea 0 MARIA JUEGA.sdf
1 ERROR(ES)
```

Y si te aparece un salto de línea se me ocurre que lo podría llegar a tener `oracion`, por lo que podrías hacer `str(oracion).strip()`

Comment: 'cadena = 'linea'+" "+str(i)+" "+str(oracion)+" "+"SINTANXIS OK"+"\n"' en la imagen se ve que me genera el salto de linea @PatricioMoracho

Comment: En todo caso lo que debiera salirte es `Linea 0 MARIA JUEGA.sdf\n SINTAXIS OK`, por eso digo que tu ejemplo está mal. De cualquier forma si tenés un salto de línea en el medio de la cadena, lo único que se me ocurre como te dije es que este en la variable `oracion`

Comment: @Efrainrodc como dice Patricio la única posibilidad para que ocurra tu salida es que oración sea en realidad `"MARIA JUEGA.SDF\n"`. Apostaría que estas tomando la línea de otro archivo de texto sin eliminar el salto de línea, usa `str.strip()` como se te recomienda. Por otro lado sería más fácil usar `str.format` para construir la cadena: `cadena = 'linea {} {} {} ERROR(ES)\n'.format(i, oracion.strip(), cont)`